# PHP Submit Form with button in dhtmlxgrid on click "save" didn't start form

Tags: php, javascript, grid, dhtmlx

I have a row table that edits a `PHP_Obj` with a `$_POST` form.

Now I have introduced a dhtmlxgrid and the php form didn't submit on click Grid_Button: "save".

in the script:

```
toolbar.attachEvent("onClick", function(id){  

             if(id=="salva"){
                 var id = tbl1.cells(1,0).getValue();

                    document.formSalva.Salva.value = id;
                    document.formSalva.submit();

             }
```

in the HTML:

this is in the Grid_Row that is created dynamically with PHP.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="formSalva" id="formSalva">
       <input type="hidden" "id="Salva" value="" name ="Salva"/>
 </form>
```

the FORM response is in the same page but is never called! Why? 
where are all my errors?